# how to display message like "Record Already Exist" or "Error Happen" in Alertbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, nopcommerce

I am using **kendo ui grid** view and also use inline editing in **NopCommerce**.

now i want to check exist(for only one field) or not and if exist then not insert record in table this thing working fine.

but no any message display like `"Record Already Exist" or "Error Happen".`

and i see code of language resource string gird view and its working fine but i am not understand how to fire alert and display message as well.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in nopCommerce 3.30 which did not properly display this error (fixed in the upcoming version 3.40).

You can return an error text the following way for grids:

```
return Json(new DataSourceResult() { Errors = "Your error text here" });
```